# Stepping Through the Stack with MASM

Tags: masm

I am trying to write a simple assembly application that reads characters in from a user and then checks if the string entered could be considered an integer.

```
mov       ebx,esp
input:
get_ch    eax
cmp       eax,0dh
je        continue
push      eax
jmp       input

continue:
put_str    0ah

xor       edx,edx
output:
```

This is where I am lost...

```
put_ch    dword ptr [ebx-4][edx]
dec       edx
jmp       output
```

...with the [ebx-4] and edx = 0, I can output the first character.  After that it seems to be outputting spaces or null characters.

Any help or links to references will be much appreciated, I am having a hard time finding something I can look up for MASM.

Answer (score 1):

1) I'm not familiar with put_ch or get_ch, but I assume that put_ch    dword ptr [ebx-4][edx] needs a ',' between the EBX and the EDX calls.

2) You change the EDX, by -1 each iteration, but the pointer (EBX) is always at ebx-4. Correct me if I am wrong, but shouldn't you change EBX? I don't think -4 actually subtracts from EBX in each iterational run.

3) I think if you subtract from 0, as you do in EBX, in assembly you only set the Overflow Flag (OF), or at least the SF (sign flag). Check your flags for the implementation of ASM you are using and see what commands set which flags.

Comment: I'm afraid you're wrong on all three points. First, [ebx-4][edx] does not need a ',' "between the EBX and the EDX calls" because it uses based indexed addressing, which is why this code can be successfully assembled. put_ch in this case is a macro. Second, the loop decrements EDX, which in my perspective, attempts to change the effective address of [ebx-4][edx] to point to the items pushed on the list, from first to last. Third, OF is only set when the signed two's-complement result does not fit in the number of bits used for the operation. SF _will_ be set after decrementing from 0.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are needlessly subtracting 4 from the effective address of your output loop. Perhaps you were thinking that the brackets are used for multiplication. This is not the case; that type of addressing is not supported by IA-32. In your code, you put...

```
put_ch    dword ptr [ebx-4][edx]
dec       edx
jmp       output
```

In the first instruction of the first iteration of the loop, as the effective address for the *put_ch* macro results in -4, relative to the top of the stack frame (EBX). This number, representing an address on the stack, will be passed to the macro to successfully print the ASCII code. However, because of the *dec edx* instruction, the second iteration will fail, as the program will then call *put_ch* with an argument of -5. Since the dword of this address will, almost without a doubt, contain 0, *put_ch* will register it as a NULL character, signaling the end of the string.
Try this:

```
dec       edx
put_ch    dword ptr [ebx][edx*4]
jmp       output
```

Here, EDX is decremented *first* and is used in the macro as an index to be multiplied by four. Thus, the first address passed to *put_ch* would be -4. The second address passed would be -8. Third would be -12, and so on...

Finally, I *strongly* suggest, when comparing the returned value of get_ch with 0dh (carriage return), for you to use AL (1 byte) rather than EAX (4 bytes) in case the upper 3 bytes of EAX contain arbitrary data.

Good luck.